# What's the name of the trope where a character answers the phone expecting someone and it's someone else?

Tags: trope

Often used in horror movies, when the female victim answers the phone, jumping straight into conversation assuming it's their girlfriend, and it ends up being the killer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we go by TV tropes, this trope would be a variant of the [Evil Phone](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EvilPhone) trope. I would call it *The Reverse Evil Phone*. In the *Evil Phone* trope the character thinks it's the killer calling, but it ends up being someone else, which then guarantees the next call will be from the killer but the character think it's the first caller calling back. The scenario you describe would therefore be a *Reverse Evil Phone* trope.

Comment: Sounds about right. I wondered this after watching this situation *not* happen in How Do You Know, and found myself relieved because I'm so fed up of seeing it happen!

Comment: oddly enough, I cannot find a TV Tropes entry for the sit-com variant of this, where a person answers the phone and starts cursing at the caller (assuming it is the previous caller, whom they are angry with, calling back) and it turns out to be their grandmother.